# Qt & Raspberry Pi take the response value of a terminal command

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I want to read the temperature of the CPU on my board (the typical command "/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp" in Raspbian) I can execute the order when I click the button, but I can't find the way to save result in a variable on my Qt program.

The code:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>

QProcess process;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QProcess lecturatemp;
lecturatemp.startDetached("/bin/sh",QStringList()<<"-c"<<"/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"); //
//lecturatemp.waitForFinished();
}
```

Comment: Removed noise, fixed syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html), QProcess is a subclass of QIODevice, so you can read the return value as if it was a file, like this:

```
QByteArray result = lecturatemp.readAll();
```

If you instead want to read the output of the process, you should read the "**Communicating via Channels**" paragraph:

> Processes have two predefined output channels: The standard output
>   channel (stdout) supplies regular console output, and the standard
>   error channel (stderr) usually supplies the errors that are printed by
>   the process. These channels represent two separate streams of data.
>   You can toggle between them by calling setReadChannel(). QProcess
>   emits readyRead() when data is available on the current read channel.
>   It also emits readyReadStandardOutput() when new standard output data
>   is available, and when new standard error data is available,
>   readyReadStandardError() is emitted. Instead of calling read(),
>   readLine(), or getChar(), you can explicitly read all data from either
>   of the two channels by calling readAllStandardOutput() or
>   readAllStandardError().

So basically call the following and you should get the output:

```
QByteArray result = lecturatemp.readAllStandardOutput();
or
QByteArray result = lecturatemp.readAllStandardError();
```